# rails button_tag vs. button_to - class & id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a button with an id and a class with rails. A javascript event fires when the button get clicked. I tried different things none of them ticks all the boxes.

```
  <%= button_tag "Launch the js event", id: "button-feedback-by-bullet" %>
```

This works but there is no class

```
  <%= button_tag "Launch the js event", id: "button-feedback-by-bullet", class: "btn-primary" %>
```

I get an error saying there are too many arguments

```
  <%= button_to "Launch the js event", id: "button-feedback-by-bullet", class: "btn-primary" %>
```

I get the right class but the button pass a post method and the js event does not get fired

Could you please help me find the right syntax and understand nuances between button_tag and button_to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> button_tag(content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block) public

You should do

```
<%= button_tag "Launch the js event", {id: "button-feedback-by-bullet", class: "btn-primary"} %>
```

or with `button_to`

> button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

```
<%= button_to "Launch the js event", {}, {id: "button-feedback-by-bullet", class: "btn-primary"} %>
```

Also, `button_tag` or `button_to` **triggers a `submit` by default**, perhaps you should use `link_to` instead